# an error comes when installing che on minikube using chectl

Tags: minikube

the command i tried: `$ chectl server:deploy --platform minikube`.

the error is:

```
Starting...failed
        → Failed to start a pod, reason: Error, exitCode: 255.
```

I already running instance of `minikube` with this command:

`$ minikube start --addons=ingress --vm=true --memory=8192`

A spell ago it worked correctly but when i rebooted without `server:delete`, I faced the error.

Could you answer this question?
Is there some great developer using `che` and `minikube`?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Did you try to restart kubelet using `$ systemctl restart kubelet` ? Also can you share output of `$ kubectl get all -n eclipse-che` do you have any errors in pods, crash loop? To sum up, you got this issue once you turn off vm and turn it on without any additional commands?

Comment: thank you for your answer. i did solve the problem. i did uninstall kubectl, minikube, chectl and docker and reinstall all of them. when i rebooted and use the command systemctl restart, it didn't work. whatever thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

i did solve the problem. i did uninstall kubectl, minikube, chectl and docker and reinstall all of them.